# Save all whatsapp profile pictures to sdcard

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I'm writting an app on android that needs to access the profile pictures of someones WhatsApp contacts. 
I know that when I click on the contact and then enlarge the profile picture it will be saved on the sdcard under `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Profile Pictures`.
So my question is there any possible way to trigger this saving image process for all contacts once in java?

Comment: Profile pictures are not always stored on an sd card. You can never just assume that they are stored in that exact path.

Comment: Ok maybe the path will change, but when I enlarge the picture it will be downloaded and stored at the SD right? Is it possible to trigger the download somehow?

Comment: If you are developing for Android 2.3 or higher, you can assume there is always an SD card (or a [virtual SD card partition](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.3.html#storage)). As far as integrating with whatsapp is concerned, you need to look through their api.

Comment: yes the location of the pictures is not the problem, its the way to trigger the download of all whatsapp-contact-pictures?

Comment: Based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318004/whatsapp-api-integration-with-android), I don't believe what you are trying to do can be done. You can wade through the "unofficial" api, but it could break at any moment.